# Grammatical function of "neither"

Tags: grammar, distributives

What's the grammatical function of "neither", in the following?

> What day is it today - the 18th or the 19th? Neither. it's the 20th.

Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Functionally, it's an adjunct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare answer "Neither." in this context is a shortened form of "It is neither the 19th nor the 20th". It is a conjunction. See
[AHD "neither" 1](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=neither)